# How to change the text and title of legend in ggplot with several variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to fix my legend text so that the text is representing the appropriate symbols and color. However, I have a lot of variables that I need to include in the legend, and they are all in different columns. Does anyone know a quick way to indicate what the colours and symbol are in the ggplot legend?

Here is some sample code

```
#sample data
temps = data.frame(Temperature= c(15,25,35), 
                                    Growth.Phase = c("exponential", "stationary", "death"),
                                    Carbohydrates = sample(c(3:10), 9, replace = T),
                                    Lipids = sample(c(10:25), 9, replace = T),
                   Chlorophyll = sample(c(2:15), 9),
                   DNA.RNA = sample(c(3:15), 9),
                   Protein = sample(c(5:20), 9))

temps$Shape = if_else(temps$Growth.Phase == "exponential", 21,
                      if_else(temps$Growth.Phase == "stationary", 22, 23))

#Graph code
ggplot(data = temps, aes(x = Temperature, y = "Proportions", shape = factor(Shape))) +
  geom_point(aes(y = Carbohydrates),colour = "darkred", 
             fill = "darkred", size = 3) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Carbohydrates), size = 1, col = "darkred") +
  geom_point(aes(y = Lipids), colour = "darkblue", 
             fill = "darkblue", size = 3, col ="darkblue") + 
  geom_line(aes(y = Lipids), size = 1) +
  geom_point(aes(y = Protein), colour = "violet", 
             fill = "violet", size = 3) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Protein), size = 1, col ="violet") +
  geom_point(aes(y = DNA.RNA), colour = "darkorange",
             fill = "darkorange", size = 3) +
  geom_line(aes(y = DNA.RNA), size = 1, col = "darkorange") +
  geom_point(aes(y = Chlorophyll), size = 3, colour = "darkgreen",
             fill = "darkgreen") +
  geom_line(aes(y = Chlorophyll), size = 1, col = "darkgreen") +
  labs(x = "Temperature (°C)", y = "Proportion")
```

This is the image I am getting

[image]

But as you can see it's not giving me the correct text in the legend. I would like the symbols to specify which `Growth.Phase` they are and the colour to specify what column I have plotted (ie. Carbohydrate, Protein etc....). Does anyone know a quick fix?

When I use my own data this is what the graph looks like, please note the lines are going through the same symbols, and are the same colours

[image]

Comment: Do you need the first or the second graph ?

Comment: I need the second graph.... but with an adjusted legend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure whether I got the legend right. But the idea is the same as in @dc37's answer. Your plot can be considerably simplified using `pivot_longer`:

```r
#sample data
temps = data.frame(Temperature= c(15,25,35), 
                   Growth.Phase = c("exponential", "stationary", "death"),
                   Carbohydrates = sample(c(3:10), 9, replace = T),
                   Lipids = sample(c(10:25), 9, replace = T),
                   Chlorophyll = sample(c(2:15), 9),
                   DNA.RNA = sample(c(3:15), 9),
                   Protein = sample(c(5:20), 9))

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)

temps_long <- temps %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(Temperature, Growth.Phase)) %>% 
  mutate(
    shape = case_when(
      Growth.Phase == "exponential" ~ 21,
      Growth.Phase == "stationary" ~ 22,
      TRUE ~ 23
    ),
    color = case_when(
      name == "Carbohydrates" ~ "darkred",
      name == "Lipids" ~ "darkblue",
      name == "Protein" ~ "violet",
      name == "DNA.RNA" ~ "darkorange",
      name == "Chlorophyll" ~ "darkgreen",
      TRUE ~ NA_character_
  ),
  )

# named color vector
colors <- select(temps_long, name, color) %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  deframe()
# named shape vector
shapes <- select(temps_long, Growth.Phase, shape) %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  deframe()

ggplot(data = temps_long, aes(x = Temperature, y = value, shape = Growth.Phase, color = name, fill = name, group = Temperature)) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  geom_line(size = 1) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = shapes) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colors) +
  scale_color_manual(values = colors) +
  labs(x = "Temperature (C)", y = "Proportion", color = "XXXX") +
  guides(fill = FALSE, shape = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = "black")))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Really interesting answer ;) I learn some stuffs today thank to you ;)

Answer (score 2):

In order to make your code simpler and not have to repeat several times the same line, you can transform your data into a longer format and then use those new variables to attribute `color`, `fill` and `shape` arguments in your `aes`.

Then, using `scale_color_manual` or `scale_shape_manual`, you can set appropriate color and shape.

In order to add lines between appropriate points, I add a "rep" column in order to mimick the rpesence of replicate in your experiments. Otherwise, `geom_line` can't decide which points are associated together.

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

temps %>% mutate(Rep = rep(1:3,each = 3)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = Carbohydrates:Protein, names_to = "Type", values_to = "proportions") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Temperature, y = proportions))+
  geom_point(aes(fill = Type, shape = Growth.Phase, color = Type), size = 3)+
  geom_line(aes( color = Type, group =interaction(Rep, Type)))+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("darkred","darkgreen","darkorange","darkblue","violet"))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("darkred","darkgreen","darkorange","darkblue","violet"))+
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(23,21,22))+
  labs(x = "Temperature (°C)", y = "Proportion")
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?

Comment: Almost, the only problem with this code is that the lines are going straight up and down. But I want the lines to go through the same symbols and colours.

Comment: I edited my answer accordingly, but your dataset was missing an information in order to link correctly points together.

Comment: This still isn't right, if you look at my second image you can see the lines are going through the SAME symbol. So the triangle symbol is seen in 15, 25, and 35 and I need the line to connect those 3 triangles... which is indicating the growth phase

Comment: Based on the dataset you have provided, the symbol is different for each temperature. For example, all values with a temperatures 15C have the same symbol corresponding to the shape 21 and the growth phase "exponential"

Comment: So, with your example, lines can't go through the same symbol because there is not the same symbol in each temperature

Comment: ohhhhhh, right. Ok let me try a new sample data. Sorry about that

Comment: No problem. But I think that based on your second graph and answers provided, you should have enough information to select the right variable for drawing your lines.

Comment: Yeah I was trying to change it before, but I'm not sure what you're doing with the code.. ```Rep =```, and what that represents

Comment: Rep was to be bale to link point depending on the temperature. But I guess for you, you should remove Rep and try to replace it with `group = interaction(Type, Growth.Phase)` in `geom_line`